# The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I linked my Google Developer Console to my Google Play Developer Console, but i'm still getting this error. I added a new in app purchase item to my app, but it still doesn't work. Here is the response that i got:

```
{
   "error": {
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
      "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
      "code": 403
    }
}
```

Here is the link that i tried to enter from OAuth 2.0 Playground : https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/myPackageName/reviews

Comment: unfortunately not